# error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a class template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to compile a code and I get error messages. The first one:
 ../base/cmvs/../stann/sep_float.hpp:50:7: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a class template
 class numeric_limits >

Here is the file:

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class sep_float;

namespace std
{
template<>
class numeric_limits<sep_float<float> >
{
public:
    static const bool is_specialized = true;
    static float max() throw() {return numeric_limits<float>::max();}
    static float min() throw() {return  -numeric_limits<float>::max();}
 };
```

This is not my own code and I am not so advanced in c++. Any idea of what I can do to fix it?

Comment: i have a question , why are you trying to redefine STD ?

Comment: @skillerdz that's how you redefine numerical limits for custom types.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher , you simply shoulld include <limits>

Comment: Not for custom types `numeric_limits<sep_float<float> >`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that this header should be self sufficient and include the header that declares this type traits :

```
#include <limits>
```

Be aware that adding `using namespace std` is more than a bad practice in a header. Remove it.